# Encrypt SQL connection string

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection

I know how to use `System.Configuration.SectionInformation.ProtectSection` to encrypt and decrypt connection string in `app.config` (`VS 2010`, `C#`, `.Net 3.5`), however I suppose that any one who know this method can take the encrypted string and decrypt it, right?

If not, please tell me why. If yes, is there any work around? I searched but could not find any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324258/is-configurationmanage-section-sectioninformation-protectsection-machine-de which has a really good answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: no, not what I need.

Comment: Why the sql tag? (I see no SQL connection at all.)

Comment: Have you looked into RSA? `new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider()`

Comment: No, because the encryption key is stored on your PC. So 'any one' would need to have access to your computer to decrypt the section. As explained in the link provided by @RobLang

Comment: I've popped an answer in for clarity, in case anyone else asks the question in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a string is encrypted it uses a certificate installed on the machine to perform the encryption so you would need the string *and* the machine key to decrypt it.

The full instructions on encrypting sections of the configuration are on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To decrypt connection string info you can use below method:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
   section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
   config.Save();
}
```

Read the full information from this **[article](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Encrypting-Connection-String.aspx)**.