# How to encrypt app config and use the application on a network

Tags: c#, encryption

I encypted the appconfig like this , on my computer works well but on a network doesn't work

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigName);

            ConnectionStringsSection section =
            config.GetSection("connectionStrings")
            as ConnectionStringsSection;

            if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
                    "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");

                config.Save();
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");


            }
```

Comment: What is "on a network"? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

`DataProtectionConfigurationProvider` is machine-dependent.  You can't encrypt it on your workstation and expect it to work on the server by default. You could use `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider` and export the keys as needed.  Or just encrypt it on the server itself.

See this [related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324258/is-configurationmanage-section-sectioninformation-protectsection-machine-de)

Comment: could you tell how to import the keys??

Comment: [Here's one way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294226/encrypt-and-deploy-app-config)

Comment: in the application I use c# linq do you think the firt method is the best than the other that said  "In a connected and client/server scenario I propose you a solution that I have adopted in a wide network is of not distribute connection string in app.config but of require the connection's information at a service that can be an web service or a RESTful service after the user authentication."

Comment: another question: if i do the encrypt like the first method I always have to shared the appconfig?Because the application is used on a network (just one  installer)